# Can't able to move any objects in any layout in android studios 3.4.1

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-studio-3.4

i am new to android programming and stuck with layouts. Whenever i drag and drop any object in relative layout i go to top left corner of layout.

I tried this with linear layout and same thing happens in parent layout  [text view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PG8TI.png)

[design view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWJ5p.png)

Because of this problem i cant design me app properly.

Comment: You should learn Layouts and their properties in Android

Comment: Not all android layouts allow free placement of children. Each layout allows different way to organize its children (LinearLayout always has them in a line for example), you should read more on which layout does what. Oftentimes building an android ui is somewhat similar to making an html document.

Answer (score 0):

RelativeLayouts define the position their child Views by (hence the name) based on existing sibling Views and the RelativeLayout itself. Since you haven't defined any of these attributes (like `android:centerInParent="true"` or `android:alignParentTop="true"` and other good stuff) it stays in the upper left corner. Also, I strongly recommend making your layouts using XML (You can edit the XML in the "Text" view at the bottom of the layout editor) because a layout made using, for example, a Pixel 2 in landscape mode will look **very** different to a Nexus 7 in Portrait mode.

EDIT: For an Android Development for Beginners course I strongly recommend this Udacity course [here](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud834)

EDIT2: You need to define ContraintLayout constraints or the content will stay in the corner.